# Mysql query "reports" with several equal tags

Tags: mysql, tags

I have a database which stores reports, and every report has several tags. The relationship between tags and reports is stored in a table called report_tags.

As you can see Report 39 and 40 have two equal tags. I want them as a result.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `report_tags` (
  `Report_ID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Tag_ID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Report_ID`,`Tag_ID`),
  KEY `tagid_fk` (`Tag_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `report_tags` (`Report_ID`, `Tag_ID`) VALUES 
(22, 8),(32, 8),(33, 8),(38, 8),(37, 244),(37, 245),(38, 246),(38, 247),(38, 248),(39, 249),(39, 250),(39, 251),(40, 251),(39, 252),(40, 252);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with joins:

```
select rt1.report_id, rt2.report_id, count(*) as numtagsincommon
from report_tags rt1 join
     report_tags rt2
     on rt1.tag_id = rt2.tag_id and rt1.report_id < rt2.report_id 
group by rt1.report_id, rt2.report_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1) is a SQL Fiddle (albeit using Postgres with one additional value paid).

Comment: Sadly i get no results on that query. I added some values to my question. As you can see report 39 and 40 have several equal tags. That are the results i want as a result

Comment: @Macster . . . I think I overthought it he first time.  The above should work.

Comment: According to the specification, the COUNT(*) is only really required at the end

Comment: @Strawberry . . . *I* want to see how many tags they two records have in common.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That works great. Thanks.This helps me a lot.